# what would be the best way to make unordered list (ul) responsive?

Tags: css, html-table, html-lists, responsive

I have some data and would like to organise them in a responsive way. It does not have to be unordered list, can be divs or anything else really. 
I would like to see first 6 elements in a row on a big screen, then the next 6 etc. see the picture below.

[image: data in a table]

on smaller screen 4 and 2 on the smallest. What do you recon would be the best way to use? flex? floats? grid? 
Dont want to use tables.

domainname:

something.com

sld:

something

tld:

com

backend:

Veri

registrant:

DEMYS-C-1999

admin:

DEMYS-C-1999

tech:

C-1999

billing:

-C-1999

status:

clientUpdateProhibited
clientDeleteProhibited
clientTransferProhibited

authinfo:

C4m7

lapse:

0000-00-00 00:00:00

locked:

0

ROID:

24660317_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN

missioncritical:

1

domaincreation:

2000-04-11 09:40:35

domainexpiration:

2027-04-30 11:59:59

domainupdate:

2017-09-27 10:24:51

domainportfolio:

2002-04-12 00:00:00

dnsaverage:

1294753

additional:

{"custom

account:

2005

ID:

2438

created:

2016-01-13 09:44:03

updated:

2017-11-14 21:20:12

changed:

onSaveCallbacks:

accountname:

Demo

accountid:

20059

organisation:

Limited

nameservers:

ns0.

Comment: Do you use any framework like bootstrap or so ?

Comment: well, you can definitely do that using grids/flexbox with media queries together.

Comment: This question is either **too broad, opinion based** or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: In this case I would use css -> column-count: $number-of-columns; and media queries to change the column number.